# How to add search icon in Vaadin ComboBox?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I have a `ComboBox` that allows selection of the given items, and an icon that accepts the selection:

[image: mine]

the functionality is all fine.

I'm looking for the effect to get the search icon into the comboBox. like in [Vaadin Icons](https://vaadin.com/icons):

[image: vaadin]

How is this done?

I tried

```
comboBox.setIcon(new ThemeResource("search.png"));
```

it didn't do any change.

backend developer here - not good on front-end tools.

//==========================================

EDIT:

one thing i can think of is to make the border of `ComboBox` disappear (don't know yet how), and make a border on the component that contains both the icon and the `comboBox`. 
is there another/better way?

Comment: Which theme are you using? Valo?

Comment: it's the one Vaadin created when i was creating the project. didn't temper any with the themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, looking at that page's source, and I could be wrong but, it does not seem to be a standard Vaadin combo-box

[image: Differences between combos]

An alternative workaround based on your discussion with @defaultlocale, could be grouping a button with the combo like this

[image: Combo with basic button on the left]

or this:

[image: Combo with "friendly" button on the right]

Anyway, you can tweak the code below to your liking and you can also check out the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo/ComboBoxes.java) of the [sampler](https://vaadin.com/valo) for more examples.

```
public class ComboWithIcon extends CssLayout {
    public ComboWithIcon() {
        // basic item configuration
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        
        Button searchButton = new Button();
        searchButton.setIcon(VaadinIcons.SEARCH);
        searchButton.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_FRIENDLY); // remove this to have a regular button
        searchButton.addClickListener(event -> {/* add button listener here */ });

        // add components to the layout - switch these to have the button to the left of the combo
        addComponent(comboBox);
        addComponent(searchButton);

        // set group style
        addStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);
    }
}
```

---

## Later edit

Based on the above and your later edit, you can also remove their borders, group them within a layout and add the layout to a panel for the *overall* border effect (there is probably a more elegant solution to get the border, but I haven't found any default styles and I don't have more time to investigate, so suggestions are welcome):

```
public class ComboWithIcon extends Panel {
    public ComboWithIcon() {
        // basic item configuration
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.addStyleName(ValoTheme.COMBOBOX_BORDERLESS);

        Button searchButton = new Button();
        searchButton.setIcon(VaadinIcons.SEARCH);
        searchButton.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_BORDERLESS_COLORED);
        searchButton.addStyleName("no-focus"); // remove the annoying focus effect
        searchButton.addClickListener(event -> {/* add button listener here */ });

        // add components to the layout - switch these to have the button to the left of the combo
        CssLayout layout = new CssLayout(searchButton, comboBox);
        // set group style
        layout.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);

        setContent(layout);
        setWidthUndefined(); // fit the component widths instead of expanding by default
    }
}
```

with a minor theme tweak to avoid the focus style on the button

```css
.v-button-no-focus:after {
  content: none;
}
```

and get:

[image: Borderless button and combo in panel]

Comment: Now, that's an excellent answer! I wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: @defaultlocale thanks for the vote of confidence :-). It's not perfect either with all its quirks, but at least it's a starting point

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can take the css from [Vaadin Icons page](https://vaadin.com/icons) and adjust it to suit your application.

Sample java code:

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox("Combobox");
comboBox.addStyleName("searchbox");
```

Sample SASS:

```
.v-filterselect-searchbox:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f002"; //search icon
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.v-filterselect-searchbox .v-filterselect-input{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

You'll probably need to adjust offset values to align the icon properly in your theme. Also, you'll have to set the combobox width explicitly, since input text padding is set in CSS.

```
comboBox.setWidth("400px");
```

The end result:

[image]

Comment: worked. but how do i put a listener on the icon? i'm looking to use that icon as a button

Comment: @ash__999, In this example, you won't be able to do it. You can try to create a button and move it inside the input with CSS. Another option is to implement a whole new component with GWT. P.S. In [your example](https://vaadin.com/icons) the icon is used for decoration only. You might want to update your question to include all the necessary requirements.

Comment: I cannot imagine just yet how do you "create a button and move it inside the input with CSS". You mean manipulating z-index values or something?

Comment: @zygimantus Frankly, I didn't put much effort into this comment and I don't remember what exactly I had in mind. Most probably I was thinking about moving the button on top of the input field. Something similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/5e6doc0m/3/

Comment: Thanks, @defaultlocale